# run function when previous function ended

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 functions in my code.

```
//Function 1 
function clr_Panel( var1 , var2 , var3 , ... ) { 
    //$(RunFunction).delay( time )
}

// Function 1 have a delay time

//Function 2 
function Show_Panel( par1 , par2 , par3 , ... ) { 
    //run This function when Function 1 ended
}
```

I need function 2  to run when function 1 ends.
how would I achieve it?

Comment: Call function2 at the end of function1

Comment: call function 2 in last line of function 1.

Comment: Please use callbacks. Just calling function 2 in the last line of function 1 is wrong. Because its not guaranteed that its called after all steps before are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need CALLBACK

```
//Function 1 
function clr_Panel( var1 , var2 , var3 , CALLBACK ) { 
    //-- do you stuff
    CALLBACK(); //Call when you need
}

//Function 2 
function Show_Panel( ) { 
    //run This function when Function 1 ended
}
```

NOW call as

```
clr_Panel( var1 , var2 , var3 , Show_Panel);
```